# Create the inboud/outbound rules by Cloudformation

Tags: json, aws-cloudformation

In my security Group, I have these rules :

[image]

[image]

This is what I created in my cloudformation template :

```
{
    "SecurityGroupIngress": [
        {
            "IpProtocol": "NFS",
            "FromPort": "tcp",
            "ToPort": "2049",
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
    ],
    "SecurityGroupEgress": [
        {
            "IpProtocol": "All traffic",
            "FromPort": "All",
            "ToPort": "All",
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
    ]
}
```

But during the creation of the stack I got the error :  `Encountered non numeric value for property FromPort`
I need to know what values correspond to All Trafic and from port tcp
Any idea how to create the rules properly with the correct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means what it says - 'tcp' is not a port, it's a protocol. You need to give a number, like 25 (SMTP) or 22 (SSH). The Docs specify the parameter expects an integer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-fromport

'All' is not going to cut it either, and doesn't really make sense. You need to bind to a port even if you are permitting all CIDR blocks (0.0.0.0/0)